I am having a problem with VMware
Hi guys I hope you are doing well.
Look recently I am having this issue in VMware, that graphics in some applications such as Duolingo or Discord doesn't load correctly while in Oracle virtualbox everything seems ok, the Vmware tools are installed and I tried to search and do more research to fix it.
But it seems I have to ask.
Does anyone knows what is this problem
Image
This is my problem with this ubuntu in vmware
I even istalled the other ubuntu but its the same problem.

Is this a Ubuntu problem, there is no mention of a Ubuntu version in the question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Well the ubuntu version is 22.04 something, and I downloaded this duolingo in ubuntu store
